# Accord.NET matrix multiplication

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, accord.net

In Accord.NET (C#) how can I multiply a matrix with a scalar? Extension methods introduced in Wiki pages do not seem to work. I have tried the following examples from the author and the wiki pages on GitHub but none of them worked: 
http://crsouza.com/2010/08/10/matrix-manipulation-using-accord-net/
[enter link description here](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation you use:

```
C = A.Multiply(B);
```

Where A is a Matrix and B is a Scalar.

So to multiply a matrix, A by 3, you would write

```
C = A.Multiply(3);
```

Comment: Yes this should work but for some reason the extension methods do not work; meaning it does not understand that a double[,] is a matrix. May I ask what is the version I should be using? I can get this to work in Visual Studio (where I have installed accord.net via nuget) but for multiple reasons I have to work in another code editor; where I can only add reference to the right dll. What would be the right dll to use?

Comment: I am just trying the example code from the Wiki Pages:  double[] v = { 4, 5, 6 };

double[] a = v.Multiply(2);     // v .* 2: { 8,  10,  12 }
double[] b = v.Divide(2);       // v ./ 2: { 2,  2.5,  3 }
double[] c = v.Pow(2);          // v .^ 2: { 16,  25, 36 }

Comment: Do you have using Accord.Math; at the top of the program?

Comment: yes. but just realized I cannot add reference to the newest version of the dll. My code editor gives me this error when trying to load the newest dll: //Import failed for 'C:\Accord.NET-3.6.0-libsonly\Release\netstandard2.0\Accord.Math.dll': Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Accord.NET-3.6.0-libsonly\Release\netstandard2.0\Accord.Math.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Comment: Thanks for your responses; finally figured out that there was an issue with not unblocking the release zip/rar folder downloaded from GitHub; that's why it was working in Visual Studio but not in the other code editor. However, after having loaded the new dll for .NET 4.5 I still don't have access to all extension methods!

Comment: If you are not installing the project through NuGet, make sure to add a reference to the Accord.Math.Core.dll assembly as well - this assembly contains the extension methods you are looking for (which are auto-generated and can take lots of time to get compiled, and for this reason were implemented into a separate assembly that is almost never re-compiled)

Comment: In the worst case, please use Elementwise.Multiply(a, b) instead of the extension method. If you are still struggling with this issue, please open a new issue report at the project's issue tracker and I will investigate.